# If an infinite group $G$ is generated by two elements $a,b$ such that $a^n=b^n=e$, must $x^n=e$ have infinitely many solutions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups

Suppose that $G$ is an infinite group, $a,b\in G$ satisfy $G=\langle a,b\rangle$ and $a^n=b^n=e$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$, where $e$ is the identity of $G$. Must $G$ contain infinitely many $x$ such that $x^n=e$?

The result is almost obvious for $n=2$: we have $((ab)^ra)^2=(b(ab)^s)^2=e$ for all $r,s\in\mathbb{N}$. If $x^2=e$ has only finitely many solutions, then $(ab)^ra=(ab)^{r'}a$ for some $r\neq r'$, or $b(ab)^s=b(ab)^{s'}$ for some $s\neq s'$, or $(ab)^ra=b(ab)^s$ for some $r,s$. In either case, there is some $m$ such that $(ab)^m=e$ ($e=r'-r$ in the first case, $s'-s$ in the second case and $r+s+1$ in the third case), and it turns out that $G$ is a subgroup of $D_{2m}$, the dihedral group of order $2m$, which is a finite group.

What can be said for general $n$? Any help appreciated.

**Edit:** Since the result has been proven to be true, there is a consequence that may appear to be interesting: suppose that every finite subgroup of $G$ is cyclic, then for every $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$, $x^n=e$ has either at most $n$ solutions or infinitely many solutions.

Prove: Fix $n$, suppose that $x^n=1$ has only finitely many solutions. Let $S$ be the set of solutions. If there exists $a,b\in S$ such that $\langle a,b\rangle$ is infinite, then $\langle a,b\rangle$ contains infinitely many $x$ such that $x^n=e$, a contradiction; so the subgroup generated by every two elements in $S$ is finite (and thus cyclic), which means that every two elements in $S$ commute, so $\langle S\rangle$ is finite (and thus cyclic, actually equal to $S$), which means that $x^n=1$ has at most $n$ solutions.

Of course the converse is not true, as shown by the example $D_\infty\times C_{2m}$, where $D_\infty$ is the infinite dihedral group ($x^n=1$ has at most $n$ solutions for odd $n$ and infinitely many solutions for even $n$, but the group contains infinitely many subgroups isomorphic to $C_2\times C_{2m}$ which is not cyclic).

**Edit 2:** The result above is already contained by the comment of Mikko Korhonen to the answer.

Comment: In general, if $x$ has order $n,$ then any $gxg^{-1}$ has order $n.$ So, for a counter-example, you'd need to find an infinite group generated by $a,b$ where the complements of $a,b$ are finite

Comment: So the set of elements $g$ such that $gag^{-1}=a$ would be a subgroup with a finite quotient. Not sure how that helps.

Comment: Follow up Mariano Suárez-Álvarez's comment, there is a theorem of Schur that says that if $|G:Z(G)|$ is finite, then the commutator subgroup $[G,G]$ is finite. But then, if $G$ is generated by two elements of finite order, then $G$ must be finite. So the answer to your question is yes. I don't know whether that can be proved without using Schur's theorem.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for the help provided! (Sorry I cannot @ all of those who have commented at a time.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To provide an answer, here is a summary of the comments.

The answer to the question is yes, there are infinitely many elements in $G$ with $x^n=1$.

For suppose not. Then $a$ and $b$ have finitely many conjugates, so their centralizers $C_G(a)$ and $C_G(b)$ both have finite index in $G$, and hence so does their intersection $C_G(a) \cap C_G(b)$. But $C_G(a) \cap C_G(b) = C_G(\langle a,b \rangle) = C_G(G) = Z(G)$, so $|G:Z(G)|$ is finite.

Now, by a well-known result of Schur (the proof is not difficult provided that you are familiar with the transfer homomorphism), $|G:Z(G)|$ finite implies that $[G,G]$ is finite. Then, since the images of $a$ and $b$ have finite order in the abelian group $G/[G,G]$ which they generate, $G/[G,G]$ is finite and hence $G$ is finite, contrary to the assumption.

Comment: More generally, with a similar proof: if $S = \{x \in G : x^n = 1\}$ is a finite set, then the subgroup generated by $S$ is finite.

Comment: Also, there is "Dietzmann's lemma". Suppose that $S$ is a finite subset of $G$, consisting of elements of finite order. Furthermore, assume that $S$ is closed under conjugation in $G$. Then the subgroup generated by $S$ is finite. The same proof with Schur's theorem should work. 

A short proof without using Schur's theorem is for example in Lemma 9 of "D. S. Passman, Nil ideals in group rings, Michigan Math. J. 9(4): 375-384 (December 1962)" [DOI link](https://doi.org/10.1307/mmj/1028998773).